# want to only allow git branch names that begin with specific words and have lowercase characters only

Tags: git, githooks

I'm trying to set up a git hook where it checks if a branch name begins with certain words, only has lowercase letters and is 15 characters or less. I have it partially working. The 'lowercase only' and '15 characters or less' parts of the regex work. I can't get the 'begins with specific words' part of the regex to work.

Here is my git hook pre-push file contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LC_ALL=C

local_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

valid_branch_regex="^(task|master|develop|qa|tb|bug|story)\/[a-z0-9._-]{2,15}$"

message="This branch violates the branch naming rules. Please rename your branch."

if [[ ! $local_branch =~ $valid_branch_regex ]]
then
    echo "$message"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

I created a new branch locally called task_7777 and ran `git push`. The branch name failed the regex check even though the name starts with 'task'.

I only want branch names that start with either "task, master, develop, qa, tb, bug or story", and only allow lowercase letters, numbers, dashes and underscores, and contain 15 characters or less. I tried modelled my code after the example in this post: https://itnext.io/using-git-hooks-to-enforce-branch-naming-policy-ffd81fa01e5e

How do I get the 'begins with specific words' part of the regex to work?

Comment: your regex requires a `/` between the first word and the rest of it -- your example doesn't have that

Comment: I have `/` right after `\  (task|master|develop|qa|tb|bug|story)\/` Do you mean something else? I'm not that good with regex.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Your regex expects the `/`, so your `task_7777` example doesn't match.

Comment: `/` is a literal character whether it's escaped or not. Your description makes no mention of allowing `/` in your branch name, so it doesn't belong in your regex at all.

Comment: I see. The regex is looking for the `/` and didn't find it. I actually don't need the `/`. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change the regex to not require the `/` after the keyword:

```
^(task|master|develop|qa|tb|bug|story)[a-z0-9._-]{2,15}$
```

Then you still have the issue that your length restriction only restricts the part after the keyword, which is probably not what you want. To fix this you need to separate the tests since `bash` does not support [lookahead zero-length assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
valid_keyword_regex="^(task|master|develop|qa|tb|bug|story)"

valid_length_regex="^[a-z0-9._-]{2,15}$"
```

If both tests succeed you have a valid branch name.

Comment: Generally I found https://regex101.com/ to be a good tool when working with regular expressions. One nice feature is a "debugger" so you can actually see why your regex fails to match.

Comment: `bash` doesn't use Perl-style regular expressions; `(?=...)` isn't available.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for pointing that out. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @SebDieBin Thanks. I'm fine with restricting the length after the keyword. I'll just shorten the length number to say 10 instead of 15. I'm trying to get the devs on my team to 1. not have long branch names and 2. not combine multiple work items into one branch. This should accomplish that.

Comment: The regex check works great. Thank you everyone for their help and suggestions.